# Autofilter using variable Criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to put an autofilter on a worksheet using a variable, but it is not working.

```
  Dim Criteria As Object
  i = 1
  Set Criteria = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
  MsgBox (Criteria.Value) ' this returns BC01.03
```

However, when I try to filter "Criteria.Value" is not returning anything.

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BM$204").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=" & Criteria.Value & "
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the quote marks around your Criteria1 argument:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BM$204").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Criteria.Value
```

Also, just a question why you would use late binding on a Range object?   I do use late binding for objects that would require another library/reference, but since `Range` is part of the Excel object library, I would use early binding.  I would `Dim Criteria as Range` but that's just my preference.

Comment: How would this work for a date greater than equal to start_date and less than equal to end_date ?

Comment: Hi @Vijay I don't know what you're asking in the context of this question that was closed 5.5 years ago. If you have your own problem, please consider to ask your own question (see [ask] and take the [tour] if you're new).