# Excel Filter Data with an array using variables

Tags: excel, filter, vba

Good day.

The following code does what I want, i.e. correctly filters my data.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$791").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Delta", "Ladner", "Tsawwassen"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But, I want to use variables to change and filter different cities.
The following code gives me the accompanying string.

```
cityStr = """Delta""" & ", " & """Ladner""" & ", " & """Tsawwassen"""
returns the string:  "Delta", "Ladner", "Tsawwassen"
```

But when I put the variable into the filter statement it doesn't do anything. It doesn't matter if I use quotes around cityStr - neither works.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AV$791").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
    cityStr), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Any suggestions on how to use a variable in an array?

Thanks
Les

Comment: Did you debug and check what is the final value after the value is substituted in the variable?

Comment: Yes, the variable shows as "Delta", "Ladner", "Tsawwassen".  Autofilter doesn't seem to recognize this string if its in a variable.  The result is that nothing is filtered and creates a filtered list with nothing in it.

Comment: The autofilter works fine if I use a single variable, such as             deltaStr = "Delta" and I remove the Array.  So the autofilter statement ends with Criteria1:=deltaStr. This works fine, its the variable in an array that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Refer [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106258/autofilter-using-variable-criteria-vba)

Comment: @Nimesh:   I placed the string "Delta", "Ladner", "Tsawwassen" into a cell. I changed my code to:   dim cityStr as Object  -  set cityStr = ActiveSheet.cells(1,1)  - Criteria1:=cityStr.Value.  Unfortunately, I have the same result, which was nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wants an array, so give it an array

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10")
Dim CityStr() As Variant
CityStr() = Array("Delta", "Ladner", "octopus")
rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CityStr(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Declare a variant array, fill it with your strings, and use it as criteria1. I think you have to use a **variant** per [kb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff193884.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  That seems to have done the trick.  I will try it with different variables.