# Using a variable with Autofilter criteria1 vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, autofilter

I have been facing a very annoying issue which I cannot seem to solve when using the Autofilter criteria1 parameter in Excel 2013 VBA.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106258/autofilter-using-variable-criteria-vba) but it did not work for me

Basically I just want to pass a variable into the criteria1 parameter like below.

```
For Each Site In Worksheets("Results").Range("A2:A200")
    With Worksheets("2G Cell Data")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:O" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=Column2GSiteName, _
           Criteria1:="=*" & Site & "*", Operator:=xlAnd         
    End With
Next Site
```

No declarations made for variable "Site". The results is the filter will filter the column with criteria "Equals" symbol "*".

I noticed if i directly assign a string to the variable and place it in the criteria parameter it works fine, so I tried using CStr to convert Site to a string variable first, still did not work.

[image: Results from the Macro]

*Update: I found the code below to worked in filtering what I needed:

```
For Each Site In Worksheets("Results").Range("A2:A200")
        With Worksheets("2G Cell Data")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:O" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=Column2GSiteName, Criteria1:="=*" & Worksheets("Results").Range("A" & countSite) & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
            .Range("A1:O" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=Column2GFreq, Criteria1:="GSM900", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to deal with each filter operation one at a time or you are trying to apply multiple wildcard filters to a single filter operation.

Comment: Actually I just need to deal with each filter operation one at a time. Worksheets("Results").Range("A2:A200") contains 1 string in each cell and I want to filter one by one, i,e filter table contains string from A2, do an operation then move on to table contains string from A3 and so on.